# Who is Mr. Wrench working for at the season 3 ending of Fargo?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, fargo-tv

In the episode *Somebody to Love* (S03E10) of *Fargo*, we can see that five years after the main action

> Wrench executes Emmit Stussy.

5 years earlier, Nikki Swango leaves the suitcase of 2 million dollars (minus a few hundreds) to Wrench telling him that **she** will take care of Emmit.

So, who gave Wrench the order? I see two options:

1. Wrench may have learnt that Nikki failed to do the job, and considering that almost 2 million is a decent payment, did the hit for is former boss. But in this case, why would he wait five years?
2. V.M. Varga, who was obviously recruiting new henchmen hired Wrench, considering he was a talented hitman. It matches with Varga sociopath behaviour who may have waited that Emmit goes through his issues and have finally improved his live to give him the final hit.

There might be some clues I have missed or another third option maybe. What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Speculation and opinion ahead.

I don't think anyone gave him an order. Nikki is after Emmit because she believes he killed Ray so she's on a revenge mission to get him.

Wrench and Nikki grew close to each other, maybe even had a budding friendship of the macabre sort. He understands Nikkis need for revenge and sympathises with her.

So, I imagine at some point after she died, he gets wind of it, and begins to track down Emmit to finish her job because she wasn't able to. It took some time of course because he probably has his own stuff to deal with, and thus takes him 5 years to find out, track and plan the hit.